# How to get all old Google Calendar events on a new phone

Tags: sync, calendar, google-calendar

My Google Calendar has events going back to 2009. However, even after syncing to my phone I can only see events back to June 2022. I cannot search or reference or even see any event prior to this on my phone. Using the web version as a workaround is non-viable.

This has been an issue for as long as I can remember. There must be a way to solve this issue as not having my calendar on my phone makes the Calendar feature all but useless.

Comment: [Synchronization of Calendars, Contacts, etc.](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_sync) - explore and make an answer if it works

Comment: @beeshyams How does that help with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Google intentionally only syncs events "modified" within one year. The reasoning behind this is baffling. However, the solution is to ensure that all events are seen by Google as being modified within a year so that they are correctly synced.

The way to do this is to export your calendar and then import it again. This is a time-consuming manual process that cannot be done on mobile and requires the web version of Google Calendar.

1. Log into your account and go to you [Google Calendar settings](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings).
2. Click [Import & export](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings/export)
3. Click Export at the bottom. This will download a zip file of all your calendars. You can then upzip the individual `.ics` files.
4. If you have a lot of events and the files are much bigger than 1 MB, you will have to split them. Use the
   https://brokenvectors.github.io/ to do this. Upload each `.ics` file
   and split it so that each split file it is below ~1 MB in size. I
   recommend between 1000-2000 events per split file.
5. You can then [reimport your calendars](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings/export).
6. If you get the error "you do not have sufficient access to target calendar" there is an issue with the UIDs. I would not recommend
   following instructions online that recommend removing or editing the
   UIDs *en masse* in the `.ics` files as you run the risk of duplicate
   events. Instead, ensure you have a good backup and then completely
   delete all calendar entries before reimporting again.
7. Once you have reimported all calendar entries, go to the Google Calendar app on your Android phone and press refresh. All events
   should then be synced.